# Display all images and videos sorted base on date at a time

Tags: android, image, video, android-sdcard

I want to fetch all images and video at a time should be display based on date. **I already get images and video separately** but I want both at a time like

Last day  I added two images (I1,I2) and one video (V1) file

And today I add one other image (I3)  and video (V2) file

Then I want to display all 5 SD card data in following order

L1

L2

V1

L3

V3

Please help me.

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

this method > `file.lastModified()` gives you timeStamp of the file, You can then sort your files accordingly in list.